# Gunzip multiple files and rename them

Tags: rename, gzip

I want to know whether it is possible to `gunzip` multiple files and rename them with one command/script.

I have a bunch of files in the format:

```
test.20120708191601.DAT.3599502593.gz
test.20120708201601.DAT.99932140.gz
test.20120708204600.DAT.1184686967.gz
test.20120708212100.DAT.824089664.gz
test.20120708215100.DAT.1286044098.gz
test.20120708222100.DAT.1414234861.gz
```

I need to `gunzip` them and remove everything after the `.DAT`, to be in the format:

```
test.20120708191601.DAT
test.20120708201601.DAT
test.20120708204600.DAT
test.20120708212100.DAT
test.20120708215100.DAT
test.20120708222100.DAT
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
for file in *.gz; do
  gunzip -c "$file" > "${file/.DAT*/.DAT}"
done
```

The approach uses `gunzip`'s option to output the uncompressed stream to standard output (`-c`), so we can redirect it to another file, without a second renaming call. The renaming is done on the filename variable itself, using `bash` substitution (match any globbing pattern `.DAT*` and replace it with `.DAT`). The loop itself just iterates over files in the current directory with names ending with `.gz`.